# Kibana/nginx could not connect to elasticsearch

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

I have Elasticsearch and Kibana with nginx running on a EC2 instance but Kibana/nginx is not able to connect to Elasticsearch and I'm getting "Error Could not contact Elasticsearch at xxxxxxxx. Please ensure that Elasticsearch is reachable from your system".

When I see the nginx error logs, I get -
[error] 13067#0: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: xxxxx, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx"
[error] 13283#0: *14 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: xxxxx, server: xxxxxx, request: "GET //cgi-bin/php5 HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx"

My conf file is - http://pastebin.com/JuxifP2n